# Newbie WPF Binding Question

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, textbox

After spending a day trying to find the answer on my question I will finally ask the question. :)

Reading through the manual pages at MSDN I find I can finally remove those booring Form-populating procedures and connect each field (TextBox, CheckBox etc) to whatever property I chose.

I have a class called ArticleItem that handles all the data in this case.

VB Code:

```vb
  Public ArtItem as New ArticleItem

  Private Sub LookUpArt()
    If txtArtNo.Text.Length > 0 then
      ArtItem.Load(txtArtNo.Text)
    End If
  End Sub
```

XAML:

```xml
<Page DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

<!-- ... -->

<TextBox x:Name="txtDescr" Text="{Binding ArtItem, Path=Descr}" />
```

Now I have no problems populating the listboxes but I do not get any reaction in my textbox.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

`ArtItem` is a field, you cannot bind to fields, only to public properties. Further you need to [implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if it changes after initialization otherwise the binding will not update.

**Edit:** Your binding is broken as well, you set the path **twice**, it should be `{Binding ArtItem.Descr}` or `{Binding Path=ArtItem.Descr}` which is the same, `Descr` also needs to be a public property and `ArtItem` also needs to implement the interface.

Comment: @Jonas: I found another issue.

Comment: Okay I've given it an other shot.
My class now implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, the ArtiItem has become an Private instance ( `Private _ArtItem as New ArticleItem` ) and created a public property named `ArtItem` that returns the value.
The Descr Property also raises the `PropertyChanged` event on change.  The XAML is also updated to `Text="{Binding ArtItem.Descr}"`   But the textbox remains empty...

Comment: So both classes implement the interface and both properties you bind to via the path `ArtItem.Descr` are public and raise the respective event in the setter? If so this should work, given that the `ArtItem` is a property on your page which has been set at the DataContext and given that the DataContext is being inherited down to the TextBox. There may be other requirements that i cannot think of right now. Try to [debug the binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) and post the full code if you fail.

Comment: Does it work now? If so, that's great! (In that case you could [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) my answer)